# How many permutations of the set n={1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5} are possible without any consecutive identical elements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I understand that there are
$\frac{8!}{3!2!}$=3600 permutations possible without any restrictions in place. I follow this by attaching all like elements as such {1,2,{3,3,3},{4,4},5} where I can account for 5! permutations where I have three 3s *and* two 4s in consecutive positions. However, when it comes to accounting for the permutations that, for example, will have three consecutives 3s but not so for the 4s, I am at a loss. I wrote some simple code and came up with a set of 960 permutations as the acceptable answer. As the question implies, I am unsure of how to reach that through other means. My apologies if this is considered elementary and I appreciate any help whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways to approach it -

First place $1,2, 5$ ($3!$ ways). Then,

i) Place two $4$'s in four places between $\{ \ 1 \ 2 \ 5 \ \}$. You then have five digits and hence six places in between where you can place $3$.

So number of arrangements $ = \displaystyle 3! {4 \choose 2} {6 \choose 3} = 720$.

ii) Place both $4$'s in one of the four places between $\{ \ 1 \ 2 \ 5 \ \}$ separated by a $3 \ (434$ being together). With $434$ being together, you now have five places and choose two places for remaining two $3$'s.

Number of arrangements $ = \displaystyle 3! {4 \choose 1} {5 \choose 2} = 240$.

So, total number of valid arrangements $ = 720 + 240 = 960$.

Answer (score 4):

Arrangements with $3's$ apart ($4's$ unrestricted), eg

$\uparrow2\uparrow 1\uparrow 4\uparrow 4\uparrow 5\uparrow \implies \frac{5!}{2!}\binom 6 3 = 1200$

Subtract arrangements with $3's$ apart but  $4's$ together

$\uparrow 1\uparrow44\uparrow2\uparrow5\uparrow \implies 4!\binom53 = 240$